# Command line backup of my DVD

Tags: bash, backup, dvd

I am trying to follow the directions to create an automated backup from this site for my 11.10 machine:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=363666

The DVD that I'm working with is a Memorex DVD-RW 4x 4.7GB 10min.

I have written the following script:

```
#/bin/bash
DVD=/dev/scd0
outfile=/var/log/burn-backup.log
echo > $outfile
echo Formatting $DVD...|tee $outfile
dvd+rw-format -force=full $DVD|tee $outfile
echo Writing $DVD...|tee $outfile
growisofs -dvd-compat -input-charset=ISO-8859-1 -Z $DVD -R -J -pad -graft-points "/spenser=/mnt/backup" 
eject
```

And here are my results:

```
thom@thom-desktop:/usr/local/bin$ sudo burn-backup.sh
Formatting /dev/scd0...
* BD/DVD±RW/-RAM format utility by <appro@fy.chalmers.se>, version 7.1.
:-( mounted media doesn't appear to be DVD±RW, DVD-RAM or Blu-ray
Writing /dev/scd0...
:-( /dev/scd0: media is not recognized as recordable DVD: 0
```

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed...

Thanks.

Comment: According to the [`dvd+rw-format` website](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/linux/DVD+RW/), that program is a "patch" for the 2.4 kernel. The 2.4 series is many years old (2.6 was out for close to 10 years, I think, and now we're on 3.0), and your UbuntuForums tutorial link is from 2007. There's a good chance that your instructions are outdated. I'm posting this as a comment because I don't know how to manually burn a DVD. I always use some GUI program to do it for me and have done so even in the days where I used the command line for everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's the script I ended up writing. Hope this helps someone else.

First you must unmount the drive to insure it is not open, the format, then copy the files.

Thanks!

```
#/bin/bash
DVD=/dev/scd0
outfile=/var/log/burn-backup.log
echo > $outfile
echo unmounting $DVD...|tee -a $outfile
umount $DVD
echo Formatting $DVD...|tee -a $outfile
wodim -vv dev=$DVD blank=all|tee -a $outfile
echo Mounting...|tee -a $outfile
mount /mnt/backup
echo Writing $DVD...|tee -a $outfile
growisofs -dvd-compat -input-charset=ISO-8859-1 -Z $DVD -R -J -pad -graft-points "/spenser=/mnt/backup"
eject
```

Comment: You should use `tee -a` instead of `tee` to *append* to the log file instead of overwriting it, which I assume is the case.